# Save output from biopython object into a file?

Tags: python, biopython, genbank

Here i have a code written to extract "locus_tag" of gene using "id". How can i save the output from this into a file in a tab seperated format????code adopted and modified https://www.biostars.org/p/110284/

```
from Bio import SeqIO
foo = open("geneid.txt")
lines = foo.read().splitlines()

genbank_file = open("example.gbk")

for record in SeqIO.parse(genbank_file, "genbank"):
    for f in record.features:
        if f.type == "CDS" and "protein_id" in f.qualifiers:
            protein_id = f.qualifiers["protein_id"][0]
            if protein_id  in lines:
                print f.qualifiers["protein_id"][0],f.qualifiers["locus_tag"][0]
```

Comment: You have provided a dead link.

Comment: Thanks, its working now

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this -- but you will need to make certain the indentations are correct with the code that you have already written.

```
with open(your_outputFileName, 'w') as outputFile:
         string = '\t'.join([f.qualifiers['protein_id'][0],f.qualifiers['locus_tag'][0]])

         outputFile.write(string + '\n')
```

You should also consider opening your initial file using "with". This will automatically close the file when you are done with it -- otherwise -- be certain to close the file (e.g., foo.close()).

```
   for record in SeqIO.parse(genbank_file, 'genbank'):
      for f in record.features:
         if f.type == 'CDS' and 'protein_id' in f.qualifiers:
            protein_id = f.qualifiers['protein_id'][0]
            if protein_id  in lines:
               print f.qualifiers['protein_id'][0],f.qualifiers['locus_tag'][0]
               with open('your_outputFileName', 'w') as outputFile:
                  string = '\t'.join([f.qualifiers['protein_id'][0],f.qualifiers['locus_tag'][0]]) + '\n'
                  outputFile.write(string)
```

Comment: Hi Thank you very much, but it saves only final protein_id and locus_tag into the file. Do we have to use append or something for this?

Comment: What happens when you do "print(lines)" right after the codeline: lines = foo.read().splitlines()?